# Paint-like app where textboxes can be readjsuted

Tags: images, drawing

Currently I am editing some comics. After cleaning of text, I would like to add textboxes in the cleared bubbles. However, in MS Paint, once I am done with a particular text box I can not readjust or reedit them.

I tried using LibreOffice Draw and google drawing, but I just want to readjust the photos and not deal with the canvas or background.

Comment: You can try an old version of Fotografix.

Comment: Any more advanced graphics editor should do, honestly.